# How do I import correctly using Maven Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I imported the `org.apache.commons:commons-email` via the command `ALT + SHIFT + CTRL + S` Android Studio. The class identified without problems but I can't build the project
PS: I went into the error directory and has only one `activation- 1.1.1.jar` file
[image: Import my dependencies]

> 21:30:01 Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 34 sec
>
> Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
> /home/daniela/AndroidStudioProjects/ConectaSP/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt File 1:
> /home/daniela/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar
> File 2:
> /home/daniela/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/485de3a253e23f645037828c07f1d7f1af40763a/activation-1.1.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue with Apache imports.
You need to add:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

to your build.grade. You might then get some other errors, follow this pattern and keep adding excludes until it will compile.